# How to enter Greek characters in Emacs

Tags: emacs

[This](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/emacs_n_unicode.html) page indicates that Greek letters can be inserted into Emacs by using `M-i`. However, Emacs 23.2.1 in a Debian Squeeze variant inserts the "tab" character when `M-i` is pressed. How can I insert Greek letters such α and β in Emacs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use another prefix, like:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x <ESC> a") "α")
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x <ESC> b") "β")
```

Or use `global-abbrev-table` as it's explained on the page you mentioned.

Comment: Each of the letters required has to be copied and pasted initially though, but otherwise it's a workable solution.

Comment: This doesn't work if I want to search for those characters interactively. Starting `C-s` and pressing the combination inserts the character into the buffer instead of searching for it.

Answer (score 71):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `set-input-method RET TeX` will allow you to write e.g. `\beta` to get `β`, `\sum` or `\Sigma` to get `Σ` etc.

It can be toggled on and off with `toggle-input-method`, bound to <kbd>C-\</kbd> and  <kbd>C-<</kbd>.

Answer (score 26):

You can use `ucs-insert` bound to
<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd> to insert any Unicode
characters by name or by value.

For example to insert a lambda you can do

- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd> `GREEK SMALL LETTER LAMBDA` <kbd>RET</kbd> → λ
- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd> `03bb` <kbd>RET</kbd> → λ

A tab-completion is also available.

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>`* lambda`<kbd>TAB</kbd>
will list every unicode characters ended by a lambda.

Comment: It's called `insert-char` now.

Answer (score 14):

You can set your input method to Greek:

```
M-x set-input-method RET greek
```

or

```
C-x RET C-\ greek
```

(which is the same).  To set the input method back press `C-\` (`toggle-input-method`).

Comment: This is the correct answer, nothing to install, all greek letters available. Nice.

Answer (score 9):

Expanding the answer by @Oleg Pavliv:

To solve this problem once and for all in your `.emacs` file, you need to choose a key pattern (like `M-g + <latin letter>`) and a memorizable correspondence table `<greek letter> - <latin letter>`. I suggest not to invent anything new, but to use the correspondences from the PostScript Symbol encoding. This leads me to the following:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g a") "α")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g b") "β")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g g") "γ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g d") "δ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g e") "ε")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g z") "ζ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g h") "η")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g q") "θ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g i") "ι")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g k") "κ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g l") "λ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g m") "μ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g n") "ν")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g x") "ξ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g o") "ο")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g p") "π")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g r") "ρ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g s") "σ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g t") "τ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g u") "υ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g f") "ϕ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g j") "φ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g c") "χ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g y") "ψ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g w") "ω")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g A") "Α")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g B") "Β")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g G") "Γ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g D") "Δ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g E") "Ε")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g Z") "Ζ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g H") "Η")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g Q") "Θ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g I") "Ι")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g K") "Κ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g L") "Λ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g M") "Μ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g N") "Ν")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g X") "Ξ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g O") "Ο")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g P") "Π")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g R") "Ρ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g S") "Σ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g T") "Τ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g U") "Υ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g F") "Φ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g J") "Φ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g C") "Χ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g Y") "Ψ")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g W") "Ω")
```

Comment: This is handy, but beware that it will mask the default `M-g` mapping to `mark-paragraph`.

Comment: Unfortunately this will only work when typing text inside a buffer, not when entering text a the result of a prompt, like a search triggered by C-s. The C-x 8 RET method is longer to type but works in C-s prompts.  If instead of using global-set-key you use `(define-key key-translation-map ....)` then it works inside the search prompt.  Also the list will then show up in which-key display.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to sporadically insert Greek characters in Emacs is to use **abbrev-mode** with [this abbrev table of Greek letters](https://gist.github.com/egarson/5800285).

To use the above gist, start emacs and invoke `M-x edit-abbrevs` which will start the Abbrevs editor. Then cut and paste the *definitions* within it under the `(global-abbrev-table)` section (to make them globally available) or place them underneath another heading e.g. `(text-mode-abbrev-table)`.

Ensure to enable abbrev-mode in a given buffer with *M-x abbrev-mode RET*, or enable abbrev-mode **globally** by adding `(setq-default abbrev-mode t)` to your init file. Alternatively if you want to enable abbrev-mode only for e.g. text and derived modes, use `(add-hook 'text-mode-hook (lambda () (abbrev-mode 1)))`.

See [the emacs wiki about abbrev-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AbbrevMode) for more.

Answer (score 3):

`C-x 8 RET`, as described by @Daimrod above, is fine for a one-off insertion.

If you want to bind a key to insert a given Unicode character: Load library [`ucs-cmds.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/ucs-cmds.el), then use `C-1 C-x 8 RET`. That inserts the character you choose and also creates a command with the same name, which you can bind to a key.

For example, `C-1 C-x 8 RET GREEK SMALL LETTER LAMBDA RET` defines command `greek-small-letter-lambda`, which inserts that character when called.

You can create multiple such commands at once, using macro `ucsc-make-commands`, also from [`ucs-cmds.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/ucs-cmds.el).  For example, to create individual commands for **each** of the Greek letters, just do this:

```
  (ucsc-make-commands "^greek [a-z]+ letter")
```

Then you can bind, say, command `greek-small-letter-beta` to `C-c b` or whatever:

```
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-c b") 'greek-small-letter-beta)
```

Answer (score 3):

A cousin of Rasmus' answer for non-TeX/LaTeX needs:

```
M-x set-input-method RET C-\ greek RET
or
                 C-x RET C-\ greek RET
```

OR

```
M-x set-input-method RET C-\ greek-babel RET
or
                 C-x RET C-\ greek-babel RET
```

Either of these give you input methods where typing for instance the single keystroke, 'a' simply gets you an alpha (α), 'b'  gets you a beta (β) and so forth.

After that, all you have to type is

```
C-\
```

to toggle back and forth from your default input method to the greek method very quickly. Quite handy.

But you have to watch out: The keys don't always match the sounds. For instance, typing hello gets you ηελλο. This is because they made it so the 'h' key becomes a greek eta (η), simply because the η looks like an h, and because the capital Greek eta (H) is the same as our 'H', even though it was pronounced differently.

The advantage of the greek-babel input method over just the greek will be appreciated mostly by those who work with the more advanced/complicated Attic Greek, which used a lot of accents. (Attic was used in Athens in Plato's time ~400BC, although the accents and lower-case letters were added centuries later.) You can hit the two keys < o and you get ὁ. The backwards apostrophe is an 'h' sound, called a 'rough breathing' -- thus ὁ is pronounced 'ho'. Accents are super easy and FAST. And you can combine accents over the same character. For instance, hit the three keys > ' a and you get ἄ. If you don't need the accents, just use the greek input method.

With both the greek and greek-babel input methods, you can also hit C-h C-\ to get a Help buffer on the input method, which includes a lovely table of all the possible keystroke combinations available to you. (C-x o to move to next window, so you can get to that info window and scroll down..)

See also https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InputMethods

Comment: I don't know if this was always the case, but at least in 26.1 C-\ is all that's required: upon the first invocation it simply asks what input method to use for subsequent toggles.

Answer (score 1):

To **find out** how to enter a **single character** that you already see somewhere on the screen, you can copy-paste that character to some emacs buffer/file, and then call `M-x describe-char`. With α, it yields

> ```
> [...] to input: type "C-x 8 RET 3b1" or "C-x 8 RET GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA" [...]
> ```

PS: re [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/580010/sabrewolfy), try also `['a'] * 28`

Answer (score 1):

The TeX input method is great for entering symbols in general, but if you're typing them with any frequency (e.g. if you're typing `λ` in some functional programming language), it will quickly become a drag to type `\lambda` every time you want to insert a Greek letter.

On the other hand, the Greek input method can be efficient for Greek letters, and is a clean solution since it leverages Emacs's built-in Greek support, but it isn't very useful as a default input method.

You can combine the benefits of both approaches like so (put somewhere in your Emacs init config):

```
(progn
  ;; conveniently enter math and greek symbols

  ;; leverage built-in input methods support in emacs to enter greek letters
  ;; by using the prefix ",."
  ;; adapted from https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/53810
  (set-input-method "greek")
  (setq greek-map (quail-map))

  ;; add a translation rule to the TeX input method to delegate to
  ;; the greek input method
  (set-input-method "TeX")
  (quail-defrule ",." greek-map)

  ;; set default input method to TeX so that it can be activated
  ;; with C-\, e.g. to enter math or other symbols in general
  (setq default-input-method "TeX"))
```

This uses the TeX input method as the default, but augments it with a rule to temporarily delegate to the Greek input method when the prefix `,.` is used.

Examples:

```
,.a => α
,.l => λ
,.v => ω
\to => →
\circ = ∘
^2 => ²
_i => ᵢ
```

Sources:

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/53810

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10197062/323874

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49765665/323874

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/419

Answer (score 0):

In Spacemacs

```
M-m i u
```

That gives you a helm to search by name the symbol you want.