# Emacs: open file with greek letters

Tags: emacs, encoding

I write my SQL-queries with Emacs. Now, I encountered the following problem. I have a query which has the greek letter `μ`.

```
SELECT *
FROM tab.labor
WHERE unit = 'μg/l'
```

To write the `μ`, I used the suggestion from [greek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192341/how-to-enter-greek-characters-in-emacs):

```
M-x set-input-method RET TeX
```

and to go back:

```
M-x toggle-input-method
```

When I close the file and reopen it, I got the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab.labor
WHERE unit = 'Î¼g/l'
```

If I open the file with notepad I got the correct version. How can I set Emacs to get greek letters?

Thanks for help.

PS:
Windows 7
GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601)

Comment: Fixed your "entering μ in SO" problem. You may want to keep in mind that, whenever your "weird" character is replaced by three other weird characters, it's almost always the UTF-8 encoding :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks. I see:  `μ'. I couldn't find it in the help. Yes, it is an encoding problem, one of the most difficult problem for non-professional programmaers.

Comment: @paxdiablo: It's (new) Greek, that ends up as two characters. Chinese code points end up as 3 characters. Old Greek may end up as 4 characters.

Comment: @giordano: You actually may want to use `µ` instead (U+00BE), which is the actual micro-sign instead of the `μ` (U+03BC) which is the Greek letter mu.

Comment: I believe I read recently that Windows uses utf-16, in which case that may very likely be the actual encoding for the file (given that Notepad has no issues with it). Worth checking, at least.

Comment: When I substitute the weird character with μ and close the file and reopen it, μ remains. The next day when I started the PC and reopen the file the weird character reappears again instead of μ. If I do C-X RET f it dispay utf-8. What happend when restart the PC?

Comment: @MSalters Thanks to you I find out another way to insert symbols: using unicode with C-x 8 RET. But 00be gives me ¾.

Comment: @phils: Notepad uses UTF-16, UTF-8 or the local character set. The fact that you see **two** characters in Emacs is a dead giveaway that Notepad correctly renders UTF-8 as UTF-8, but Emacs renders UTF-8 as an unknown 8 bit charset.

Answer (score 2):

Try `M-x revert-buffer-with-coding-system` and specify `utf-8`.  It looks like the file was saved in UTF-8, but Emacs opened it as Latin-1 for some reason.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but the weird characters remained.

Comment: @giordano: It helps to remember that the file contains bits, not characters. Emacs displaying it incorrectly is a matter of interpretation, the bits are correct UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the encoding of the file you want to open:

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>`utf-8`<kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd>`filename`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for answer. I open the file with "weird" characters (file x.sql) and entered the commands as you described. The weird characaters remains. How can I change the "weird" characters into greek letters?

Comment: @giordano: What encoding is the file saved in? Try also `utf-16` or whatever.

Comment: The default encoding is utf-8. I tried other encodings but nothing changed. At the end I arrived to the conclusion that I have to write again a μ with the above method and replace all Î¼g with μ. I don't know why μ changed to Î¼g. I will see if this happened again in the future and pay more attention when it changed again to weird characters.